# write dynamic frame on s3 with xml format with custom rowtag and roottag specified

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark-pandas

I used the below code, but I am getting rootTag as 'root', and rowTag as 'record'. But I want rootTag as 'SET'and rowtag as 'TRECORD'

repartitioned_df = df.repartition(1)
datasink4 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame = repartitioned_df, connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"path": "s3://datalaketest1/temp"}, format = "xml", transformation_ctx = "datasink4")

Is there some way.

Comment: For some reason Amazon decided to remove it from the spark-xml fork. Did you find a workaround?